# How do I pass the value of Row() into the ArrayFormula function in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, row, spreadsheet

I want to always have the current Row number in this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(match(2,1/(A5:5<>""))))
```

The `ROW()` function works for getting the current row number. How can I implement it into this `ArrayFormula()` like this? I imagine it working like this but it doesn't:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(match(2,1/(A&ROW():ROW()<>""))))
```

How do I pass the value of `Row()` into the `ArrayFormula()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not an arrayformula issue...

constructed range always needs to be INDIRECTed:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(2, 1/(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":"&ROW())<>""))))
```